# SVD: proof of existence

Tags: compactness, svd

I'm reading "Numerical Linear Algebra" by Lloyd Thefethen. For Singular Value Decomposition proof of existence it starts like this: "Set $\sigma_1=||A||_2$. By a compactness argument, there must be vectors $ v_1 \in C^n$ and $u_1 \in C^m$ with $||v_1||_2=||u_1||_2=1$ and $Av_1=\sigma_1u_1$." What exactly "by a compactness argument" means? I understand it should have something to do with topological compactness, but how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $S = \{x \in \mathbb C^m \mid \|x \|_2 = 1 \}$.
Then
$\|A\|_2 = \sup_{x \in S} \|Ax\|_2$.

But the function $f:S \to \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x) = \|Ax\|_2$ is continuous, and $S$ is compact, so (by the [extreme value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem)) $f$ attains a maximum value at some point $v_1 \in S$.

Comment: thank you. That was extremely clear.

Comment: @littleO may I know why it can assert $\sigma_{1} = \| A \|_{2}$? Are there any ways to prove it? Or, it is just an elementary fact?